# How to Update an Existing Record in a Dataset

Tags: java, sql

I can't seem to update an existing record in my table using a strongly-typed dataset. I can add a new record, but if I make changes to an existing record it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
 private void AddEmplMaster()
 {           
     dsEmplMast dsEmpMst = new dsEmplMast();

     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
     cn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["cn.ConnectionString"];

     SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UPR00100", cn);
     SqlCommandBuilder cb1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(da1);

     da1.Fill(dsEmpMst.UPR00100);

     DataTable dtMst = UpdateEmpMst(dsEmpMst);
     da1.Update(dsEmpMst.UPR00100);
 }
```

This procedure is called from above to assign the changed fields to a record:

```
private DataTable UpdateEmpMst(dsEmplMast dsEmpMst)
{  
    DataTable dtMst = new DataTable();

    try
    {               
        dsEmplMast.UPR00100Row empRow =  dsEmpMst.UPR00100.NewUPR00100Row();

        empRow.EMPLOYID = txtEmplId.Text.Trim();
        empRow.LASTNAME = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
        empRow.FRSTNAME = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
        empRow.MIDLNAME = txtMidName.Text.Trim();
        empRow.ADRSCODE = "PRIMARY";
        empRow.SOCSCNUM = txtSSN.Text.Trim();
        empRow.DEPRTMNT = ddlDept.SelectedValue.Trim();
        empRow.JOBTITLE = txtJobTitle.Text.Trim();
        empRow.STRTDATE = DateTime.Today;
        empRow.EMPLOYMENTTYPE = "1";

        dsEmpMst.UPR00100.Rows.Add(empRow);

    }
    catch { }
    return dtMst;
}
```

Thank you

UPDATE:

Ok I figured it out. In my `UpdateEmpMst()` procedure I had to check if the record exists then to retrieve it first. If not then create a new record to add. Here is what I added:

```
try
{
    dsEmplMast.UPR00100Row empRow; 
    empRow = dsEmpMst.UPR00100.FindByEMPLOYID(txtEmplId.Text.Trim());

    if (empRow == null)
    {
         empRow = dsEmpMst.UPR00100.NewUPR00100Row();
         dsEmpMst.UPR00100.Rows.Add(empRow);
    }
```

then I assign my data to the new `empRow` I created and updates fine.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Please share.

Comment: Why isn't anyone replying to my post? I have 53 views but no comments/replies.

Comment: You've answered your own question right?  You might as well post it as an answer.  Note that you declare dtMst and return it without ever doing anything to it.

Comment: +1 to Abraham, looks like you answered your own question.  You could add the answer and close it out.

Comment: @hmakled: Copy your solution as an answer, and accept it. That will stop this question from showing up as an unanswered question. Thanks.

Comment: @hmakled: plus you'll get a badge.

Answer (score 1):

In order to edit an existing record in a dataset, you need to access a particular column of data in a particular row. The data in both typed and untyped datasets can be accessed via the following:
With the indices of the tables, rows, and columns collections.
By passing the table and column names as strings to their respective collections.
Although typed datasets can use the same syntax as untyped datasets, there are additional advantages to using typed datasets. For more information, see the "To update existing records using typed datasets" section below.
To update existing records in either typed or untyped datasets
Assign a value to a specific column within a DataRow object.
The table and column names of untyped datasets are not available at design time and must be accessed through their respective indices.